# Ingress not mapping to service

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress, k3s

I am trying to configure an Ingress to map to 2 different services but when I use anything other than `/` as the `path` I get a `Cannot GET /node-web-app-svc` error.  I have tried using `Exact` as the `pathType` but it doesn't help.  I am running this on a k3s cluster with Traefik.

**EDIT**

It seems like its trying to hit the deployment at an undefined path.  So i htink it actually is hitting the expected service.  Is there a way to rewrite `/node-web-app-svc` -> `/` of the service?

Here is the yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /node-web-app-svc
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: node-web-app-svc
            port:
              number: 3000
      - path: /node-web-app2-svc
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: node-web-app2-svc
            port:
              number: 3000
```

Any help here would be appreciated.  Let me know if more details would help.

Thanks

Comment: Why is your ingress called "nginx-ingress" when its `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` annotation is `traefik`? Also, have you tried to set the `pathType` to `ImplementationSpecific`?

Comment: Its called nginx-ingress because i copied and pasted a sample when originally spinning this up that was in ingress on top of a basic nginx service.

What do you mean `ImplementationSpecific`?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types).

Comment: Thanks, i just googled and changed it to that, but getting the same results.

Comment: @Riwen I just made this update above if this helps:
It seems like its trying to hit the deployment at an undefined path.  So i htink it actually is hitting the expected service.  Is there a way to rewrite `/node-web-app-svc` -> `/` of the service?

Comment: If it were nginx, I could help you with that, but unfortunately I'm not familiar with traefik. You could try the following annotations: [`traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target`](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/configuration/backends/kubernetes/), or `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root`.

Comment: That seemed to do it.  thanks! i have some concerns, but for now its doing what i expect.  thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Need to leverage `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /app-root`